# Special character in stored procedure

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, sas

I want to use a SQL procedure to pull the data from SQL to SAS EG.

But a value in one parameter (INVNO)is TN/2015-16/0005-13 ie special character.

This is causing an error:

> ERROR: CLI prepare error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Line 1: Incorrect syntax near '/'.
>   SQL statement: execute SAS_INV_RPT AMRUTFAC, SDAB, 1, TN05/000023/14-15, TN05/000024/14-15.

Can anyone come up with a workaround for this?

```
PROC SQL; 
   CONNECT TO ODBC (DSN='AHCLOD' uid=&uid pwd=&pwd); 
   CREATE TABLE sas_inv_rpt AS 
   SELECT * FROM connection to ODBC (
      execute SAS_INV_RPT 
         &COMPANY_CODE, 
         &LOCATION_CODE, 
         &LANG_ID, 
         &INVNO_min, 
         &INVNO_max); 
   DISCONNECT FROM ODBC; 
QUIT;
```

Also can I use range for text value with INVNO_min and INVNO_max prompts

Comment: If you can show what syntax works for your SQL statement and what value your SAS macro variable has perhaps someone can help you convert the macro variable value to the syntax you need.

Comment: You have several questions in your post, you're more likely to get help if you focus on one at a time. Also, as @Tom pointed out, there's a lot of things going on in your code that we can't see -- macro variables for instance. Try to make an example that would be reproducible for someone with the same setup.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first question:

Take a look at: [SAS %QUOTE and %NRQUOTE MACRO Functions](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514quote.htm)

```
PROC SQL; 
    CONNECT TO ODBC (DSN='AHCLOD' uid=&uid pwd=&pwd); 
    CREATE TABLE sas_inv_rpt AS 
        SELECT * FROM connection to ODBC 
        (execute 
           SAS_INV_RPT 
           &COMPANY_CODE, 
           &LOCATION_CODE, 
           &LANG_ID, 
           %QUOTE(&INVNO_min),  /* Mask any special chars in the resolved text*/
           %QUOTE(&INVNO_max) ); 
    DISCONNECT FROM ODBC; 
    QUIT; 
    RUN;
```